# About fwrite() errors in C

Tags: c, fwrite

Reads the file and multiplies the data by 2. After that, I wrote a
program that writes to another file. This file is a 16-bit file. By
the way, only a certain number is written to the created file. I do
not know why this is happening. Please help me.

**C (visual studio 2017)**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define SIZE 16000
typedef short data_type;

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {

    FILE *fd, *fd2;
    data_type *data;
    int n;

    data = (data_type*)malloc(sizeof(data_type) * SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        data[i] = 0;

    if ((fd = fopen("C:\\Users\\SeoHyeon\\Documents\\test16kSam16bMono.pcm", "r")) == NULL)
        printf("Error opening file1");
    if ((fd2 = fopen("C:\\Users\\SeoHyeon\\Documents\\test16kSam16bMono2.pcm", "w")) == NULL)
        printf("Error opening file2");

    n = fread(data, sizeof(data_type), SIZE, fd);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        data[i] = data[i] * 2.0;

    if (fwrite(data, sizeof(data_type), SIZE, fd2) != SIZE) {
        printf("Error writing to file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fclose(fd);
    fclose(fd2);

    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Can you adjust the `SIZE` to say 8, and add the hex-dump of two blocks of 16 bytes to your question.

Comment: I have tested this code under linux (with SIZE 8) using an input file of 16 bytes of `0x01`, and I got an output file of 16 bytes of `0x02`.  Looks like it's ok to me.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately you're going to have to provide more details before anyone can post anything other than guesses as to what is wrong. To begin with, please describe what you experienced when running the program, and what you expected it to do, this will tell us **why** you think there is something wrong as well as the expected behavior. You should also read [ask].

Comment: What is written to your file ? What did you expect to be written ? (Also your code  read 32000 bytes from your file ? is that what you want - or do you mean that the file i larger than 32000 bytes and the error is that you do not read/write the whole file ?) Please provide more explanation so the people reading your question can understand what issue you have.

Comment: @nos - The size of the file is 32 KB and is a 16-bit unit. So I read `short` (16bit, 2byte) * 16000 = 32000.

Comment: What happens if `data[i] = 32767;` to begin with before you multiply by `2.0`?

Comment: @박서현 Ok, so that is fine. What about the other things I asked about ?

Comment: @nos - The file I want to read is a voice file. My goal is to double the volume of this voice file by doubling it. If I check the output with `printf ("%hd", data [i])`, it is doubled exactly. However, after writing the data and reading it again, all the data values are 12851.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the program is not opening both the files in *binary* mode.

For example:

```
FILE *fin = fopen("input_file.bin", "rb");  // <-- Note the "rb"
```

If your file is opened in *text* mode, which is the default, if there's an EOF character in the data, the file-input could close prematurely.

EDIT: Also, you should handle the error when your file-handles `fd` and `fd2` are NULL.  There's also a couple of other error conditions you aren't checking for, but I leave these as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: One should *always* handle the error case for `fopen` when it returns a `NULL` (e.g. here when `fin` is `NULL`). Even on code which is *not* an assignment

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - normally yes, but the OP may simply be playing or experimenting, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Even in experimental code, checking result of `fopen` is important (and only adding one or two lines of C code). Otherwise, the code is likely to crash (e.g. `fread` or `fscanf` on a `NULL` file is crashing)